# When I resize my browser, my menu bar does not adjust accordingly

Tags: css

I made a menu bar that looks fine when my browser is at maximum size but, as I make it smaller, then my menu bar cannot adjust its size accordingly.
Here is my css code

```css
#dropdown ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  /*width:63%; */
  height:31px;
  list-style-type: none;   
  /*background:black;*/
  position:absolute;    
  }

#dropdown ul li {
  width: 128.83px;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 21px;
  float:left;      
  position:relative;    
  border:1px solid;
  }
#dropdown li ul {        
  display:none;
  }
#dropdown li:hover ul {      
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;
  }
#dropdown ul li a{ 
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
        background: skyblue;
        text-decoration: none;    
  }
#dropdown ul li a:hover{ 
        color: #fff;    
        background: #939393; 
  }
```

```html
<div id="dropdown">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">  Home </a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="admission.html">  Admission &#9662;</a>
  <ul> 
   <li> <a href="admission.html"> Fee Structure </a></li>
   <li><a href="merit.html"> Merit List </a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
          
   <li><a href="faculty.html">  Faculty </a></li>
   <li><a href="gallery.html">  Photo Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href="academic.html">  Academic &#9662;</a>
   <ul> 
    <li> <a href="academic.html#bscs"> BS(CS) </a></li>
    <li> <a href="academic.html#bsit"> BS(IT) </a></li>
    <li><a href="academic.html#mcs"> MCS </a></li>
   <li><a href="academic.html#mit"> MIT </a></li>
   </ul>
   </li> 
           
    <li><a href="contact.html">  Contact us </a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

[here is the snap shoot of my menu bar after restore browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZWQy.png)

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/course/responsive-web-design-fundamentals--ud893

Comment: Yes because it is not responsive. The width of your menu is larger then the screen so it comes down. Please read about Media Queries and Responsive Web Design.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are using position absolute then also define position relative for parent element ,then for  left:0;right:0; and give width to "li" items in "percentage" instead of "px".
2. do not use position absolute for  and give width to "li" items in "percentage" instead of "px".